# Aligning window text in C using Win32 API

Tags: c, winapi, text-alignment

I'm interested in finding a way to align the following text:

[image: current text]

The desired outcome would be to have the first letter of each abreviation alligned, a variable amount of space, and the colons alligned; e.g.

```
STR :0
CON :0
DEX :0
INT :0 
...
```

I understand that I could make two 'TextOut' calls for each line, one for the abbreviation and one for the ":%d", is there a way I can modify the hdc with SetTextAlignment()?

The following is an excerpt of my code:

```
...
TextOut(hdc, 10, 100, "STATS:", strlen("STATS:"));
TextOut(hdc, 17, 100+textYStep, "STR:0", 5);
TextOut(hdc, 17, 100+textYStep*2, "CON:0", 5);
TextOut(hdc, 17, 100+textYStep*3, "DEX:0", 5);
TextOut(hdc, 17, 100+textYStep*4, "INT:0", 5);
TextOut(hdc, 17, 100+textYStep*5, "WIS:0", 5);
TextOut(hdc, 17, 100+textYStep*6, "WIL:0", 5);
TextOut(hdc, 17, 100+textYStep*7, "CHR:0", 5);
...
```

Comment: Think of the text as three columns instead, one for the text, one for the colon, and one for the numbers. Then if you draw each column separately at their specific positions it's easy to align just as you like.

Comment: Yeah I see that as a potential solution, I'd just like a neat way to code it if possible

Comment: Code for drawing is seldom "neat" :)

Comment: TabbedTextOut may be useful here.

Comment: @RaymondChen Have an example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use fixed-width font, that's also what this website uses to format code:

```
HFONT hfont = (HFONT)GetStockObject(ANSI_FIXED_FONT);
```

or

```
int textYStep = 16;
HFONT hfont = CreateFont(textYStep, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    DEFAULT_QUALITY, 0, "Courier New");
HFONT oldfont = (HFONT)SelectObject(hdc, hfont);

TextOut(hdc, 10, 100, "STATS:", strlen("STATS:"));
TextOut(hdc, 17, 100 + textYStep * 1, "STR:0", 5);
TextOut(hdc, 17, 100 + textYStep * 2, "CON:0", 5);

SelectObject(hdc, oldfont);
DeleteObject(hfont);
```

Or use `TabbedTextOut` as was suggested in comments:

```
int tabs[] = { 50, 100, 150, 200 };
const char *text = "X1\tX2\tX3\tX4";
TabbedTextOut(hdc, 17, 100 + textYStep, text, strlen(text), 4, tabs, 17);
```